# Blazor gets Data and paging data back to Razor at the same time?

Tags: asp.net, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0

I refer to many Blazor teaching videos, and now I want to make a Table with paging.

Hope someone help me tell me is it overcomplicated.

I define 3 Class and 1 method to get data and assemble.

This allows me to easily write a simple loop in Html to obtain data and the number of pages at the same time.

it is work now, But I think is it too complicated?

cause Task<ServiceResponse<List<MainProductList<List>>>> is really long and too many layers.

I can't think better way, I don't want to group pagination and data together because I want pagination to share usage.

Although the tutorial is written together.

Or is there a way to make return return two objects at the same time?

```
//This is Product info

namespace SipposM2.Shared
{
    public class MainProduct
    {
        [Key]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string? CategoryName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string? CategoryDesc { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string? SyncFlag { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string? SyncType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public DateTimeOffset? EntryDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? ModifyDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
//This is Productlist page, it inculde MadinProduct data inside.

namespace SipposM2.Shared
{
    public class MainProductList<T>
    {
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
        public T? MainData { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
//ServiceResponse is return Api Response status, It Have MainProductList and MainData info

namespace SipposM2.Shared
{
    public class ServiceResponse<T>
    {
        public T? Data { get; set; }
        public bool Success { get; set; } = true;
        public string Message { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public int? StatusCodes { get; set; }
    }
```

Then is Service method

```
        public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<MainProductList<List<MainProduct>>>>> GetMainProductListAsync(int pageNo=1,string sTerm="")
        {
            var Data = await Model2_context.MainProduct
                            .Where(Product => sTerm == null || Product.CategoryName.ToLower().StartsWith(sTerm))
                            .Select(Product => new MainProduct
                            {
                                CategoryName = Product.CategoryName,
                                CategoryDesc = Product.CategoryDesc,
                                CategoryId = Product.CategoryId,
                                EntryDate = Product.EntryDate,
                                ModifyDate = Product.ModifyDate,
                                SyncFlag = Product.SyncFlag,
                                SyncType = Product.SyncType,
                            })
                            .ToListAsync();
            double totalRecords = Data.Count;
            int pageSize = 10;
            int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalRecords/ pageSize);
            int skip = (pageNo - 1) * pageSize;
            Data = Data.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList();

            var result = new MainProductList<List<MainProduct>>
            {
                MainData = Data,
                PageNumber = pageNo,
                TotalPages = totalPages,
                SearchTerm = sTerm
            };
            var response = new ServiceResponse<List<MainProductList<List<MainProduct>>>>
            {
                Data = new List<MainProductList<List<MainProduct>>> { result }
            };
            return response;
```

The data come back looks like

[image]

at last my Razor page

```
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await ProductService.GetMainProductListAsync();
        if (ProductService.MainProductList?.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
        ProductService.MainProduct = ProductService.MainProductList?.FirstOrDefault()?.MainData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I don't want to group pagination and data together because I want pagination to share usage."  I'm not sure I understand. Why not?  It all depends where you maintain the form state. Also, if this is Blazor server you can pass a  Predicate to the data provider to do the filtering.  I'll happily show you a somewhat different approach to the problem (based on `FetchData` and `WeatherForecast`) in an answer [if you want to see one].

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Yes, I really want to refer to other people's practices, and also want to know how you classify the resources used in the project?
I mean,How complex is Razor page? They will be cut into smaller components.

Answer (score 0):

While you have defined a return object `ServiceResponse`, mine would look like this:

```cs
public record ItemsQueryResult<TRecord>(IEnumerable<TRecord> Items, int TotalCount, bool Succcesful, string? Message = null) where TRecord : class;
```

This returns the result as an `IEnumerable`, a status flag and the total records in the recordset.

I would define a request object to encapsulate your request:

```cs
public record ItemsQueryRequest(int StartIndex, int PageSize, string SearchTerm);
```

For the UI list, I would define a ListState object to maintain state.  I can persist this if I wish, so if I return to the component I return to the correct page.

```cs
public class ListState
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 10;
    public int Page { get; set; } = 0;
    public int StartIndex => this.Page * this.PageSize;
    public int LastPage => ((int)Math.Ceiling(((decimal)this.TotalCount / this.PageSize))) - 1;
    public ItemsQueryRequest request => new ItemsQueryRequest(this.StartIndex, this.PageSize);
    public int TotalCount { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

My version of your service method would look like this.  I've split out the object translation into a separate method.  I've also commented the steps to explain the process.  I'm minimizing what is known as materialization i.e. the creation of new list objects.

```cs
public async ValueTask<ItemQueryResult<MainProductList> GetMainProductListAsync(ItemQueryRequest request)
{
    // You should be using a Unit of Work DbContext here

    // define the query source and the filter to apply to minimize the dataset we actually retrieve from the database 
    var query = Model2_context.MainProduct
        .Where(Product => sTerm == null || Product.CategoryName.ToLower().StartsWith(sTerm));

    // materialize the query to get the count.
    int totalRecords = await query.CountAsync();
 
    // define the page to get on thr query restricting the actual data we fetch from the database to just the page
    query = query
        .Data.Skip(request.StartIndex)
        .Take(Item.PageSize);

    // materialize the query to an in-memory list
    // we may be using a DbContext Factory so we need to ensure the IQueryable
    // is materialized into an object in memory before the context goes out of scope.
    var list = await query.ToListAsync();

    // Apply the select to the paged data query
    // You can do this before or after the query is materialized
    var items = ToMainProduct(list);

    return new ItemRequestResult<MainProductList>(items, totalRecords, true );
}
```

The select is really a data translation from the raw Dbo recordset to a DTO object: a bit of business logic.  I've separated it out.

```cs
private static IEnumerable ToMainProduct(IEnumerable query)
    => query.Select(Product => new MainProduct
        {
            CategoryName = Product.CategoryName,
            CategoryDesc = Product.CategoryDesc,
            CategoryId = Product.CategoryId,
            EntryDate = Product.EntryDate,
            ModifyDate = Product.ModifyDate,
            SyncFlag = Product.SyncFlag,
            SyncType = Product.SyncType,
        });
}
```

There's a Repo here based on the `FetchData` page and `WeatherForecast` that demonstrates these patterns in more detail - https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.ListDemo